# Euler Class Definition (Spivak)

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

In the Spivak's book on Differential Geometry Euler class $\chi(\xi)$ of an oriented $k-$plane bundle $\xi=\pi:E\to M$ is defined as
$$ s^*[\omega]\in H^k(M)$$
where $s:M\to E$ is any section and $[\omega]\in H^k_c(E)$ the Thom class represented by $\omega$ closed $k$-form with compact support on $E$.

Now for a non-zero section $s$, if we pick $c>0$ 
sufficiently large, some subset of image of $M$ under the section $c\cdot s$ will lie outside of  support $\omega$. So by definition
$$\chi(\xi)=(c\cdot s)^*[\omega]=0 \in H^k(M).$$
But why is it zero?

For example $\omega_{cs(p)}$ will be zero form for some $p\in M$. Is the form then exact?

Comment: Perhaps you want a _nowhere zero_ section instead of a nonzero section. If such a section exists, the eular class of the vector bundle is zero.

Comment: @AGlearner Could you perhaps elaborate on why should it be zero in that case. Thank you!

Comment: It is exactly what you wrote, if a section $s$ does not vanish, by scaling it will miss the support of the $\omega$, so pullback is a zero form.

Comment: And note that $M$ is compact?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes :)